# Python greed roll

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, python-2.x, dice

I am doing the [Python Koans](https://github.com/gregmalcolm/python_koans) to practise Python a bit more and I got to the [greed dice project](https://github.com/gregmalcolm/python_koans/blob/master/python2/koans/about_scoring_project.py). It is a very simple dice game that scores a set of up to five rolls.

These are the rules:

> ```
> # A greed roll is scored as follows:
> #
> # * A set of three ones is 1000 points
> #
> # * A set of three numbers (other than ones) is worth 100 times the
> #   number. (e.g. three fives is 500 points).
> #
> # * A one (that is not part of a set of three) is worth 100 points.
> #
> # * A five (that is not part of a set of three) is worth 50 points.
> #
> # * Everything else is worth 0 points.
> #
> ```

Calls are made like this:

```
score([5])
score([1, 5, 5, 1])
score([3, 3, 3])
```

This is my implementation:

```
def score(dice):
    result = 0
    if len(dice) <= 5:
        dice_copy = sorted(dice)
        dice_dict = dict((i, dice_copy.count(i)) for i in dice_copy)
        if dice_dict.get(1) >= 3:
            result += 1000
            dice_dict[1] -= 3
        for number in dice_dict:
            if dice_dict.get(number) >= 3:
                result += number * 100
                dice_dict[number] -= 3
        if 1 in dice_dict:
            result += dice_dict[1] * 100
        if 5 in dice_dict:
            result += dice_dict[5] * 50

    return result
```

I am looking for:

- comments and tips on my code
- suggestions of Python-style ways of doing this
- improvement and optimizations of my code
- ideas of how to implement this in more interesting, original or interesting ways

I sorted the list before creating the dictionary because I think that would make the dictionary creation faster, but I ran some tests and found out that sorting the list actually makes the program slightly slower. I suppose my intention would only be effective in larger lists. Is my guess right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `sorted` doesn't help; `.count` doesn't know the dictionary is sorted and so can't utilize that fact. The call to `sorted` just slows things down.

One alternative is to use a loop like

```
dice_dict = {}
for die in dice:
    if die in dice_dict:
        dice_dict[die] += 1
    else:
        dice_dict[die] = 1
```

which operates in a single pass. This is encapsulated in the `Counter` class which does the same thing with just `Counter(dice)`.

`if dice_dict.get(1) >= 3` is undefined if there are no `1`s in the input; `.get` will return `None` and `None >= 3` returns an *arbitrary* result. You should use `dice_dict.get(1, 0) >= 3`, which defaults the argument to 0.

However, if using `Counter` every value is implicitly defaulted to `0`, so you can just do `dice_dict[1] >= 3`.

Your next loop could also be fixed this way:

```
for number in dice_dict:
    if dice_dict[number] >= 3:
        result += number * 100
        dice_dict[number] -= 3
```

but you should just use `dice_dict.items()`:

```
for number, count in dice_dict.items():
    if count >= 3:
        result += number * 100
        dice_dict[number] -= 3
```

You can support `>= 5` items with a touch of math:

```
for number, count in dice_dict.items():
    result += (count // 3) * number * 100
    dice_dict[number] %= 3
```

`//` is integer division.

You can merge the first check with the second as so:

```
for number, count in dice_dict.items():
    value = 1000 if number == 1 else number * 100

    result += (count // 3) * value
    dice_dict[number] %= 3
```

Your `<= 5` check can then be removed, but if you want to keep it you should throw an error instead of silently giving the wrong result.

With `Counter` you don't need the `if x in` check; they will default to `0`.

This gives:

```
def score(dice):
    result = 0
    dice_dict = Counter(dice)

    for number, count in dice_dict.items():
        value = 1000 if number == 1 else number * 100

        result += (count // 3) * value
        dice_dict[number] %= 3

    result += dice_dict[1] * 100
    result += dice_dict[5] * 50

    return result
```

You can remove the mutation of `dice_dict` by doing modulo outside of the loop:

```
def score(dice):
    result = 0
    dice_dict = Counter(dice)

    for number, count in dice_dict.items():
        value = 1000 if number == 1 else number * 100
        result += (count // 3) * value

    result += (dice_dict[1] % 3) * 100
    result += (dice_dict[5] % 3) * 50

    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it guaranteed that the rolls are of up to `5` die? Otherwise the code doesn't work well. Also, `count` works without the sorting, so you could do directly

```
dice_dict = dict((i, dice.count(i)) for i in dice)
```

However, in this cases, it's just better to just go ahead and use the standard python library:

```
import collections
...
dice_dict = collections.Counter(dice)
```

Comment: In the last paragraph I explained why I sorted it and I also asked about my guess.

Comment: I've just updated the answer, there's an even better approach  :)

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: The `collections.Counter` is particularly designed for this. It's probably optimized for these matters, but I haven't looked too much under the hood of python to explain why or to be 100% sure of that.

Answer (score 2):

> I sorted the list before creating the dictionary because I think that would make the dictionary creation faster, but I ran some tests and found out that sorting the list actually makes the program slightly slower.

Why do you think it would be faster? Here `i` loops through all the items in the list, and sorting does not change the number of items. Neither is `count` able to skip any work, even if it called with the same argument multiple times in succession.

```
dict((i, dice_copy.count(i)) for i in dice_copy)
```

Sorting takes some time, so of course it makes the program slower.

> I suppose my intention would only be effective in larger lists. Is my guess right?

With larger lists the use of `count` becomes a serious bottleneck, because it scans the whole list every time. Thus obtaining all the counts takes *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time. Really only a single sweep through the list is necessary. `collections.Counter` will do it for you.

---

Note that these rules

```
# * A set of three ones is 1000 points
# * A one (that is not part of a set of three) is worth 100 points.
```

could be expressed in a slightly simpler way:

```
# * A one is worth 100 points.
# * A set of three ones is worth an extra 700 points
```

You could follow that idea to simplify the program logic.

---

An alternative to using several `if` statements would be to use dictionaries to represent the scores table.

```
from collections import Counter

DIE_POINTS = {1: 100, 5: 50}
TRIPLET_POINTS = {1: 1000 - 3 * DIE_POINTS[1],
                  2: 200,
                  3: 300,
                  4: 400,
                  5: 500 - 3 * DIE_POINTS[5],
                  6: 600}

def score(dice):
    result = 0
    if len(dice) <= 5:
        counts = Counter(dice)
        for number, count in counts.items():
            result += count * DIE_POINTS.get(number, 0)
            if count >= 3:
                result += TRIPLET_POINTS[number]
    return result
```

Comment: @Veedrac Yes, but `DIE_POINTS` is a regular dictionary here.